# Prevent mpv from Clearing Terminal Screen Post Video Playback

Tags: mpv

I am using `mpv` with the `--vo=tct` flag to play videos directly in the terminal. I am interested in finding out if there’s a way to prevent `mpv` from clearing the terminal screen when the video is either finished or interrupted.

I've  tried a few solutions found online, but they do not fully address my needs:

- The `--keep-open=yes` flag does stop the video at the end, but it prevents me from using the terminal unless I exit mpv, which results in the terminal being cleared.
- Suspending the process using `Ctrl + Z` is not effective as it causes the prompt’s position to overlap with the video image, resulting in a distorted display. Additionally, it conceals the cursor when typing commands.
- The `--player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui` flag somewhat works, but it suppresses the mpv output on the screen, which I need to see during video playback.

If you got any insights, I'm all ears :)